# Use eulervm number font in text

Tags: fonts, eulervm, euler

I'm currently typesetting a document with `Palatino` as main font and `eulervm` as math font.
I really do not like Palatino numbers so I typically use math mode to write number.
This however to not apply to bibliography and numbers produced by `\href` (e.g. `\ref{fig}`).
Is there a way to force `eulervm` numbers over palatino ones everywhere?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Do you can add a complete fragment + one screenshot of your problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### In the Modern Toolchain

There is a free, OpenType [version of Euler](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf) by Khaled Hosny and Hermann Zapf.  I usually pair it with Zapf’s Palatino and Optima, with Rapf Levien’s Inconsolata as a humanist monospace font.  This set-up also lets you typeset upright constants in Euler, such as `\symup{e}` or `\symup{i}`.

This sample uses as its sans-serif font URW Classico, a clone of Optima [available on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/classico) but that is not part of the distribution because of a restrictive license.

You might need to download some fonts to compile this MWE, but all you need to use Euler digits are the definitions of `\euler` and `\texteuler`.

This requires LuaLaTex or XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\pagestyle{empty}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Scale=1.0]
\setsansfont{URW Classico}
\setmonofont{Inconsolata}[
  UprightFont = *N-Regular ,
  BoldFont = *N-Bold ,
  ItalicFont = *zi4-Regular ,
  BoldItalicFont = *zi4-Bold ,
  Extension = .otf ]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont{Neo Euler}[range={up,bfup,cal,bfcal,frak,bffrak},
                        script-features={},
                        sscript-features={}]
\newfontfamily\euler{Neo Euler}

\DeclareTextFontCommand\texteuler{\euler}
\titlelabel{\texteuler{\thetitle}\quad}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}\label{sec:one}

This is Section \texteuler{\ref{sec:one}}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Pagella/Neo Euler sample]

### In the Legacy Toolchain

This version is similar to the above, but uses the Type 1 versions of the same fonts.  It compiles in PDFTeX, should you be required to use it.  You will need to download [URW Classico](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/classico) or replace that package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{eulerpx, tgpagella, classico, inconsolata}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand\euler{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{zeur}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\texteuler{\euler}
\titlelabel{\texteuler{\thetitle}\quad}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}\label{sec:one}

This is Section \texteuler{\ref{sec:one}}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Tgpagella/eulervm sample]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the examples.
Unfortunately I am using a fairly complex template (classic thesis) and I am 200 pages into my dissertation. I'm not sure I want do to something intrusive as changing all of my fonts.

Comment: @AlbertoBragagnolo Okay. If you just copy the definitions of `\euler` and `\texteuler`, wrapping your numbers in `\texteuler` will work, without changing any of your other fonts.

Comment: @AlbertoBragagnolo In other words, consider my font selections just a suggestion.

Comment: thanks, I will try. However, I do not think is the solution i'm looking for.
This approach is not applicable in various cases, such as: \autoref{}, figures/table numbers, large chunks of copy-pasted biblatex entries.

I was hoping that was a way to substitute automatically the font for the text number.

Comment: @AlbertoBragagnolo It works fine if you add a bit of formatting. If you really want every digit to be replaced by Euler automatically, you can use `\XeTeXinterchartoks`.